# Measure preserving coordinates of $S^2$ from $[0,1]^2$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider the unit sphere $S^2 = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3 ~ {\large|} ~ |x|=1 \right\}$ and denote the uniform (Lebesgue) measures on the $S^2$ and $[0,1]^2$ by $m_S$ and $m_2$, respectively.

**Question 1:** Is there a map $\phi : [0,1]^2 \to S^2$ such that preserves the uniform measure, i.e., (with a slight abuse of notation) $\phi \circ m_2 = m_S \circ \phi$?

**Question 2:** Is there a way to construct *coordinates* on $(\varphi_1(w),\varphi_2(z)):[0,1]^2 \to S^2$ such that $dm_S(\varphi_1(w),\varphi_2(z)) = dw\,dz$?

**Question 3:** Does such coordinates exist for every higher dimensions?

*Remark:* On $S^1$, this is trivial by $\varphi (t) = e^{2\pi i t}$, up to a constant.

Comment: look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_equal-area_projection

Comment: see gall-peters projection for a commonly used area preserving projection used in geographical maps.

Answer (score 2):

For Question 1, see [an earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248418/simultaneous-simulation-of-all-probability-measures-on-a-compact-metric-space). Both of the above measures can be "simulated" by measurable maps $f:[0,1]\to X$ where $X=[0,1]^2, S^2$, using the Lebesgue measure on the left. In fact, $X$ can be any compact metric space with any Borel probability measure.

This may not be the answer you want! Presumably, you are looking for continuous $\varphi$.